# how to execute stored procedure in cakephp 3?

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0

This is my function for **login** i call a stored procedure **login** for match user name and password, but it doesn't work for me it give me all the rows:

```
public function login($email,$password)
    {
    $consumers = TableRegistry::get('Consumers');
    $result=$consumers->query("Call login('".$email."','".$password."')");
    pr($result->toArray());die;
    }
```

My stored procedure in phpmyadmin is below:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM consumers WHERE email = email_id AND password =     md_password;
END
```

When i am executing query it give me object but after converting this object into array it give me all the row of table.output is:

```
<pre class="pr">Array
(
    [0] => Cake\ORM\Entity Object
        (
            [_properties:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => jeevan
                    [email] => j@gmail.com
                    [password] => asdf
                    [phone_no] => 8447726137
                    [ota] => cde
                    [status] => 0
                    [created_on] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2016-07-08 17:28:52
                            [timezone_type] => 3
                            [timezone] => UTC
                        )

                    [token_access] => 
                    [device_type] => 1
                    [push_id] => abc
                    [want_news] => 1
                    [postal_code] => 263136
                    [registration_type] => 1
                )

            [_original:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_hidden:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_virtual:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_className:protected] => 
            [_dirty:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_new:protected] => 
            [_errors:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_invalid:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_accessible:protected] => Array
                (
                    [*] => 1
                )

            [_registryAlias:protected] => Consumers
        )

    [1] => Cake\ORM\Entity Object
        (
            [_properties:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => jack
                    [email] => jack@gmail.com
                    [password] => 123
                    [phone_no] => 7409757656
                    [ota] => chb
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_on] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2016-07-20 06:10:14
                            [timezone_type] => 3
                            [timezone] => UTC
                        )

                    [token_access] => ghcvhgv
                    [device_type] => 0
                    [push_id] => hgnjh
                    [want_news] => 1
                    [postal_code] => 263136
                    [registration_type] => 1
                )

            [_original:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_hidden:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_virtual:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_className:protected] => 
            [_dirty:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_new:protected] => 
            [_errors:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_invalid:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_accessible:protected] => Array
                (
                    [*] => 1
                )

            [_registryAlias:protected] => Consumers
        )

)</pre>
```

that mean the stored procedure not working, any idea really help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a stored procedure using the `ConnectionManager`'s `execute()` method. It's important to remember to prepare the query so that you remove the risk of SQL injection:-

```
$this->connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$results = $this->connection->execute(
    'CALL login(?, ?)', 
    [$email, md5($password)]
)->fetchAll('assoc');
```

When CakePHP runs `execute()` it will substitute the `?` with the escaped and quoted values of `$email` and `md5($password)`. For further details check out the [official docs on Preparing a statement](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#preparing-a-statement).

Answer (score 0):

step 1:use the class as **use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;**
step 2: then execute the procedure-

```
$this->connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $consumer = $this->connection->execute("CALL login('".$email."','".md5($password)."')")->fetchAll('assoc');
```

now it will give an array.
finally i got this answer in cakephp cookbook.

Comment: While this will work, what you have there now is a possible SQL injection vulnerability! Either use binding/prepared statements, or manually quote the input via the drivers `quote()` method! **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#interacting-with-statements** | **http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.Connection.html#_quote**